# Filter specific text in Redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I'm trying to filter the name of a table from a text column that contains SQL script in it. Sample below:

```
**columnA**        **ColumnB**
dt_1203       CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.demand_fcst_view AS
              SELECT id,region,snapshotday,demand
              FROM dtnet.dly_demand_fcst_all a

dt_1204       CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.demand_fcst_view AS
              SELECT id,region,snapshotday,demand
              FROM salesfrc.dly_demand_fcst_all

dt_1204       CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.demand_fcst_view AS
              SELECT id,region,snapshotday,demand
              FROM salesfrc.dly_demand_fcst_all_output
```

I only want rows where the text is "dly_demand_fcst_all" as my output, irrespective of which schema the table falls under or how many times the tables repeats.

I tried the query `ColumnB like '%dly_demand_fcst_all'` it is returning zero rows.
I tried the query `ColumnB like '%dly_demand_fcst_all%'` it is returning all three rows

what am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe there's some invisible character after `dly_demand_fcst_all`? Like a space or newline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have some symbols at the end of the ColumnB.
You can try using this filter, to filter only **dly_demand_fcst_all** table, and not **dly_demand_fcst_all_**

```sql
where column_b like '%dly_demand_fcst_all%'
and column_b not like '%dly_demand_fcst_all\\_%'
```

Or you can try TRIM function, for removing spaces

```sql
where trim(column_b) like '%dly_demand_fcst_all'
```